# algorithm problem: select one number from each of the five arrays, check whether their sum can be 2018?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

**problem**:

there are five unsorted number arrays and choose only one number from each array. check whether the sum of the five numbers can be 2018. if can, return true. else, return false.

**my solution:**

the most naive one...

```
sort the array in descending order
for a in arr1:
  for b in arr2:
     for c in arr3:
        for d in arr4:
           for e in arr5:
              if a+b+c+d+e == 2018:
                  return true
return false
```

**result of my solution:**

time exceed limitation

---

this is a problem I was faced with in an interview several weeks ago. I don't know how to solve it, so write here to ask for help.

Comment: And what are the limits on each number in the array?

Comment: @ user3386109, there is no strict constraint on the limit of the number in the array for the problem given to me. so probably in int type I guess

Comment: The important piece of info here is the max number of items per array... That drives the kind of algorithm to use... Do you know that?

Comment: @ e2-e4, for the problem of the interview, the size of each array is n. but I think it doesn't make great difference  if the size of each array is different. =.=

Comment: Really? So if it is 100 or 10 millions it's the same? For a O(n^3) algo, 100^3 gives 1 million iterations, for 10^7 that's 10^7^3 iterations .....

Comment: If the numbers are all positive, then there is an easy answer. Otherwise, I'd have to go with btilly's answer.

Comment: @ user3386109, as far as I can remember, the negative number is needed. -.-, but I'm also curious about how easy the solution will be if all the numbers are positive.

Comment: @ e2-e4, sorry, I thought you mean whether size of each array is different or not. for this problem, I guess the size of the array will not so big. 0.0

Comment: With only positive numbers, it can be solved like the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) using 2018 as W. With negative numbers, you could scan the arrays for the most negative, and most positive numbers, and perhaps still solve as knapsack. But whether that's efficient would depend on how big those numbers are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple idea.  Make a sorted list `ABC` of the sums of the first 3 arrays.  Make a sorted in reverse list `DE` of the sums of the second 2 arrays.  This so far takes space `O(n^3)` and time `O(n^3 log(n))`.

And now start summing elements from `ABC` against elements of `DE`.  Every time the sum is below 2018, advance in `ABC`.  Every time it is above advance in `DE`.  If you find 2018 your answer is `True`.  Else it is `False`.  That final comparison is `O(n^3 + n^2)`.  The overall running time is `O(n^3 log(n))`.

If you're clever with priority queues you can actually generate `ABC` in sorted order using no more than `O(n^2)` memory.  The running time can't be improved though.

Comment: If insertions and lookups in a hash-table take amortized O(1) time, as is sometimes assumed, then storing the O(n^3) results in a hash-table lets you solve this in O(n^3) time; so sorting might be counterproductive.

Comment: @user3386109, sorry, I didn't pay attention to the tense of the sentence. I took that interview several weeks ago-.-

Comment: @ruakh Excellent point.  Just making a hash out of sums of 2 of them, then iterating over the other 3 gives `O(n^2)` space and `O(n^3)` time.  Don't know how I missed that solution!

Answer (score 2):

#### Your question is a derivative of the all-time most common interview question, which is [2Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/).

---

I guess this algorithm might work with these three blocks:

- Counter for a + b (array 1 and array 2)
- Counter for c + d (array 3 and arry 4)
- Loop through array 5

---

Technically, it would be three separate blocks for time complexity analysis:

```
# This block is O(N ^ 2)
for element in array 1
    for element in array 2
        generate dictionary 1 # O(N) space
# This block is O(N ^ 2)
for element in array 3
    for element in array 4
        generate dictionary 2 # O(N) space

# This block is O(N ^ 3)
for element in dictionary 1
    for element in dictionary 2
        for element in array 5
            if statement
```

Then for the space complexity, it would be two dictionaries, each one is an order of N, then the memory would be O(N).

---

This would be an `O(N ^ 3)` time and `O(N)` space solution.

#### Python

```
import collections


def five_sum(A, B, C, D, E):
    AB = collections.Counter(a + b for a in A for b in B) # O (N ^ 2)
    CD = collections.Counter(c + d for c in C for d in D) # O (N ^ 2)

    # O (N ^ 3)
    for ab in AB: 
        for cd in CD:
            for e in E:
                if ab + cd + e == 2018:
                    return True
    return False


A = [0, 2000]
B = [0, 10]
C = [0, 10]
D = [0, -1]
E = [0, -1]

print(five_sum(A, B, C, D, E))
```

#### Output

```
True
```

It is possible to make it more efficient, but I don't think the time complexity would change.

Comment: With the right choice of values, it is possible for there to be `O(n^5)` distinct sums, which makes this solution `O(n^5)` running time.  Also generating those counters takes `O(n^2)` memory.

Comment: If you think that my analysis is incorrect, point out the flaw.  But first consider that for each of `O(n^2)` elements in your outer loop you execute a middle loop over `O(n^2)` elements, and for each of those `O(n^4)` combinations you execute an inner loop of size `O(n)`.  That's the `O(n^5)` that I claimed.

Comment: Emma, it's not O(n^3). `dictionary 1` and `dictionary 2` can each be on the order of O(n^2). A nested loop just on them is O(n^4).

Comment: @גלעדברקן Off topic, but beware that if you change your username, the new rules will prevent you to use non-alpha characters... (not sure, but it seems so)